# Does IE7 compatibility mode work the same on IE9 as it works on IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I know IE7 compatibility mode isn't the same as the IE7 standalone browser, but in terms of my current set-up, which is IE8, I see certain IE7 bugs that I have to fix for the web app I'm working on.

If I upgrade to IE9, (which I'm thinking about because it has the Network tab in the dev toolbar), will I continue to see the same IE7 bugs when I view the site in IE7 mode?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, yes. Microsoft makes only very minor changes in Internet Explorer's compatibility modes (like, support for HTML5 iframe sandboxing is not included in IE9 and below, but it is supported by all IE10's compatibility modes, including quirks mode). In general, we can say that IE8-as-IE7 mode is the same as IE9-as-IE7.